# Stop AppPool before installing website with WiX

Tags: iis, wix, custom-action, wix3.9

I am trying to take an existing MSI that installs a website and add in the process of stopping the AppPool so that when installing an update you don't have to remember to stop the AppPool before running the installer.

The custom actions I've set up are listed below

```
<CustomAction Id='StopIisAppPoolCMD'
          Property='StopIisAppPool'
          Value='"[WindowsFolder]SysNative\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" stop apppool /apppool.name:"[WEB_APP_POOL_NAME]"'
          Execute='immediate' />
<CustomAction Id='StopIisAppPool'
          BinaryKey='WixCA'
          DllEntry='CAQuietExec64'
          Execute='immediate'
          Return='check' />
```

And they are scheduled in the msi product like this:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  ...
  <Custom Action="StopIisAppPool" Before="InstallValidate"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="StopIisAppPoolCMD" Before="StopIisAppPool"></Custom>
  ...
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

And the msi is wrapped in a bundle like this:

```
<Chain>
  ...
  <MsiPackage Name="MySetup.msi" DisplayInternalUI="yes"/>
</Chain>
```

When the custom actions are executed I'm getting this in the msi log

> MSI (s) (94:A8) [14:43:48:833]: Doing action: StopIisAppPoolCMD
>
> Action 14:43:48: StopIisAppPoolCMD.
>
> Action start 14:43:48: StopIisAppPoolCMD.
>
> MSI (s) (94:A8) [14:43:48:834]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding StopIisAppPool property. Its value is '"C:\WINDOWS\SysNative\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" stop apppool /apppool.name:"MyWebAppPool"'.
>
> Action ended 14:43:48: StopIisAppPoolCMD. Return value 1.
>
> MSI (s) (94:A8) [14:43:48:834]: Doing action: StopIisAppPool
>
> Action 14:43:48: StopIisAppPool.
>
> Action start 14:43:48: StopIisAppPool.
>
> MSI (s) (94:2C) [14:43:48:837]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI2B0E.tmp, Entrypoint: CAQuietExec64
>
> CAQuietExec64:  Error 0x80070057: failed to get command line data
>
> CAQuietExec64:  Error 0x80070057: failed to get Command Line
>
> CustomAction StopIisAppPool returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
>
> Action ended 14:43:48: StopIisAppPool. Return value 3.
>
> Action ended 14:43:48: INSTALL. Return value 3.

I feel like my problems are possibly because I'm trying to do `Execute='immediate'` instead of `deferred`, but if I run the custom action as `deferred`, then it has to run after `InstallInitialize` which is too late to be stopping the AppPool to avoid file in use conflicts.

I was thinking it would be possible to run as `immediate` because the msi is wrapped in a WiX bundle, so I assumed it would be running with elevated rights before `InstallInitialize` since I have to put in an Admin password before the msi installer even starts.

I've considered putting these actions in a separate msi or exe package in the bundle and running it before the msi that installs the web files, but I would really rather not since the web app pool name is retrieved from the UI that already exists for the msi and if I can avoid it I would prefer to not have to redo how the UI is handled.

Is there a simpler way of going about this? am I missing something simple? or do I really need to redo the UI and split these actions into a separate exe package or msi inside of the bundle? If that's the case I may just say forget it and just make sure everyone knows to manually stop the App Pool before installing any new versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have never had to stop the app pool before installing.  ASP.NET runs out of a temporary directory and doesn't present any file lock issues.  Also IIS automatically recycles the application pool when the web.config gets touched so all of this should be a total non issue.

Comment: I agree that this should be a non issue, but some files are being locked because when I run the installer it gives the files in use warning, and if I shutdown the app pool, then the problem goes away. Maybe we need to clean something else up rather than trying to fix this problem. I think this may be because we are using native dll's, and I know we had some issues with shadow copy because of the native dll's we were using.

Comment: Looking at the some more today, and I think the issue is because I'm trying to configure the ASP.NET application on IIS through the installer. So every time I do an install it is trying to uninstall and reinstall the ASP.NET application and web app pool. I think it's either the application or the web app pool that is seen as "in use" and is causing the popup during the install.

Answer (score 0):

As per the WiX documentation page [Quiet Execution Custom Action](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html) (underneath the "Immediate execution" heading), if your QuietExec custom action is set to `Execute="immediate"`, you need to set a property called `QtExecCmdLine` when using `CAQuietExec` or `WixQuietExecCmdLine` when using `WixQuietExec` (instead of setting a property whose name is the ID of the custom action; that method is used when your custom action is deferred, only).

This is the code that worked for me (they recommend you use the newer WixQuietExec rather than CAQuietExec):

```
<CustomAction Id="StopApplicationPool_Cmd" Property="WixQuietExecCmdLine" Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd&quot; stop apppool MyApp" Execute="immediate" />
<CustomAction Id="StopApplicationPool" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
<CustomAction Id="StartApplicationPool_Cmd" Property="WixQuietExecCmdLine" Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd&quot; start apppool MyApp" Execute="immediate" />
<CustomAction Id="StartApplicationPool" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
```

Scheduled like this:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
...
  <Custom Action="StopApplicationPool_Cmd" Before="StopApplicationPool"><![CDATA[REMOVE OR UPGRADEFOUND OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE OR REINSTALL]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="StopApplicationPool" Before="InstallValidate"><![CDATA[REMOVE OR UPGRADEFOUND OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE OR REINSTALL]]></Custom>
...
  <Custom Action="StartApplicationPool_Cmd" After="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[UPGRADEFOUND OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE OR REINSTALL]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="StartApplicationPool" After="StartApplicationPool_Cmd"><![CDATA[UPGRADEFOUND OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE OR REINSTALL]]></Custom>

...
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```